# How to validate password of a disabled AEM user?

Tags: aem, jackrabbit, crx, jackrabbit-oak

I have the authorizable ID and a password text. In a normal scenario, I can directly get the session using slingRepository.login option. If I am able to do so, that means the credentials are valid. But let's say if the user has been disabled for some reason then how can I validate the password because in that case AEM doesn't validate it and throws the AccountLockedException directly. I don't need the session, but I want to validate that the password I have is correct (programmatically).